# Performing complex nested loop?

Tags: python, loops

I have a list '`shapelist`' that has many directories to be used.
This loop has many functions and somewhere in the process I have to add another loop that will assign coordinate system to some files. How is the correct way to do it?

```
#This is the initial loop
for i in shapelist:
    arcpy.FeatureToLine_management([i] ,i.replace('ASTENOT.shp', 'ASTENOT_lines'))
    #many more lines with functions
    #at some point I have to add coordinate system information to exported files 
    #how do I do that in this loop without creating perplexing results?
```

I want to add somewhere this code that does the coordinate system assignment.

```
#Finds and stores to a list the files that need the coordinate system assignment
rootfolder = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\etg'
import os 
newlist = []
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootfolder):
    for name in files:
        if name==('centerline.shp'):
            newlist.append(os.path.join(path, name))
```

`newlist` now contains the files that need the coordinate system assignment

```
        #follows the loop that does the assignment
        for i in newlist:
    ...     sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(2100)
    ...     arcpy.DefineProjection_management(i, sr)
```

How can I add all this in the initial loop?

Comment: `sr` is being assigned there. It is a variable that contains the Spatial Reference and it's useful for the next line in the parameter where it is needed.Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Apparently the three loops are independent one from the others, why do you think they are to be _complexly_ nested?

Comment: Because they have to be inside the first one

Comment: _"Because they have to be inside the first one"_ is tautological. The second loop uses a constant root (not depending on 1st loop), the third uses the info built from the second but doesn't need  to be nested inside it (it is rather possible to write a single loop to find the files and update them). If you don't give more context, I cannot see why the second and third loops have to be nested inside  the 1st one

Comment: It has to be put at a certain point in the process of the first `for` loop because the outcome  will be used right after in another function (still in the first for loop). That's the main reason for putting it in this position.

Comment: In the code that you have shown (is there something else that you have not shown?) there are _absolutely no outcomes_ that depend on the first loop.  The only assignments in loops 2 and 3 are to `newlist` (and the outcome depends only on `rootfolder`), and to `sr` (but the right value is either a constant or the result of `arcpy.SpatialReference(2100)` is non-deterministic).

Comment: Yes. After the coordinate assignment the now assigned files are going to be used in this exact step.The code that uses them is not included as you said.So the process is like:1) Main loop 2)finding which files will be assigned with coordinate system 3) assign them 4)use the assigned files in a new function.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's difficult to test a solution for your problem without input data and an expected output and that I have never worked with ArcGIS, I can only speculate what you want to do:

```
import pathlib

# Root directory of where your files resides
rootfolder = pathlib.Path(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\etg')

# Get all files named 'centerline.shp' in this directory and all its
# sub-directories
newlist = rootfolder.glob('**/centerline.shp')

# Define a SpatialReference (?)
spatial_reference_to_use = arcpy.SpatialReference(2100)

# Assign a defined projection to all the files in newlist (?)
for file_to_assign in newlist:
    arcpy.DefineProjection_management(str(file_to_assign),
                                      spatial_reference_to_use)

# From the input file names (in newlist), define 
# the output file names (?)
newlist_out_features = [current_file.with_name('ASTENOT_lines')
                        for current_file in newlist]

# Change features to lines for all the files in newlist (?)
for (current_shape_file, current_out_features) in zip(newlist,
                                                      newlist_out_features):
    arcpy.FeatureToLine_management([str(current_shape_file)],
                                   str(current_out_features))
```

Is this something that looks like what you wanted to do? If it isn't, you'll have to explain better what you want to do.